# Running a rosjava node

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to build my own rosnode with the new gradle build system. But when I run my node with the command ./build/scripts/mynode org.ros.mynode I get the following error

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ros/RosRun
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ros.RosRun
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
```

The same happens if I try to run the pub_sub tutorial with the command

```
  ./build/scripts/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub org.ros.rosjava_tutorial_pubsub.Talker
```

After having a look at the generated script, it just sets the classpath to

```
   CLASSPATH=$APP_HOME/lib/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:$....
```

It seems that the class path is not set correctly, because APP_HOME points to pwd -P and there is no lib folder. What am I doing wrong in the execution of the rosnodes?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34480/running-a-rosjava-node/) by [Markus Eich](https://answers.ros.org/users/1686/markus-eich/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2012-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try running the tutorial using

> ./build/install/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/bin/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub org.ros.rosjava_tutorial_pubsub.Talker

The path you are using looks like it might come from an old tutorial.

A lot of the documentation on the internet is old, so be sure to check the date when you read things.  This is the best source of documentation at the moment: http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/index.html .

---

Originally posted by [amittleider](https://answers.ros.org/users/2448/amittleider/) with karma: 227 on 2012-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2